# Clear form fields after adding record to list

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable

I have a custom controller that allows users to input data in inputFields and add the record to an `apex:pageBlockTable` by hitting a button to add to the list. I would like to reset these fields each time a user inputs a record so they may enter another record.

Records users input are controlled via a custom controller method that re-instantiates a new record each time, however the previous values still remain in their fields.

[image]

How can I reset the fields here each time a user adds a record to the list?

Apex controller

```
    public with sharing class ecrjcClass{
    
    public Participant__c record {get;set;}
    public List<Participant__c> allrecords {get;set;}
    public Referral__c ref {get;set;}


    public ecrjcClass(){
        record = new Participant__c();
        allrecords = new List<Participant__c>();
        ref = new Referral__c();
    }   
    

    //Add a record row
    public pageReference Add_Row(){

        Participant__c anotherRecord = new Participant__c();   
        anotherRecord.Name = record.Name;
        anotherRecord.Last_Name__c = record.Last_Name__c;
        anotherRecord.Age__c = record.Age__c;
        anotherRecord.Victim_Offender__c = record.Victim_Offender__c;
        anotherRecord.Phone__c = record.Phone__c;
        
        insert ref;
        
        anotherRecord.Referral__c = ref.Id;
        //Issue: Need to insert ref first
        allrecords.add(anotherRecord);
        return null;        
        
    }
    
    //Save and insert records in list
    public pageReference save(){
        
        insert allrecords;
        record = null;
        //This seems to work for the first record added, adding any additional records returns an error
        return null;
            
    }
}
```

**VF markup**

```
    <apex:pageBlock >
    <!--Participant info-->
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Partipicant Information">
        <apex:inputField value="{!record.Name}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!record.Last_Name__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!record.Age__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!record.Phone__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!record.Victim_Offender__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>     
    <!--Add participant to record list-->    
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Add_Row}" value="Add Participant"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>   
    
            <apex:pageBlock title="Added Participants">
        <apex:pageBlockTable id="Participants" value="{!allrecords}" var="Participant">
            <apex:column headerValue="First Name" value="{!Participant.Name}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Last Name" value="{!Participant.Last_Name__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Age" value="{!Participant.Age__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Phone" value="{!Participant.Phone__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Victim/Offender" value="{!Participant.Victim_Offender__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Submit"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What is `insert ref;` in `Add_Row()`? To reset the form, reinitialize the record property after adding it to the `allRecordsList`: `record = new Participant__c();`

Comment: I have 2 objects in this controller where `referral__c` is the parent of `participant__c` and I need to insert it before participants are inserted in order to set it to its parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can instantiate the record variable (See second last line in the method.)

   ```
    //Add a record row
    public pageReference Add_Row(){

    Participant__c anotherRecord = new Participant__c();   
    anotherRecord.Name = record.Name;
    anotherRecord.Last_Name__c = record.Last_Name__c;
    anotherRecord.Age__c = record.Age__c;
    anotherRecord.Victim_Offender__c = record.Victim_Offender__c;
    anotherRecord.Phone__c = record.Phone__c;

    insert ref;

    anotherRecord.Referral__c = ref.Id;
    //Issue: Need to insert ref first
    allrecords.add(anotherRecord);

    // ADD THIS LINE
    record = new Participant__c();
    return null;
   ```

   }
2. Then add an `id` to the first `apex:pageBlockSection`

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="participant" title="Partipicant Information">
```

3. And then in the commandbutton `rerender` the participant Information section

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!Add_Row}" rerender="participant" value="Add Participant"/>
```

Comment: Thanks.. no errors however when I click `add participant`, it clears the form but doesn't add the participant record to the table anymore - suspect this is from `rerender`. When I remove `rerender`, it works perfectly with one record, but any additional records returns error: `Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id a074W000019TZRvQAO; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]
Error is in expression '{!Add_Row}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page ecrjc_page: Class.ecrjcClass.Add_Row: line 24, column 1`

Comment: Edit: Used `upsert` instead of `insert` - works perfectly thank you!